# PlaylistItems: list does not return videoId when using part:id without snippet

Tags: youtube-data-api

Trying to manage the "cost" of API request and so to generate a delta of videos that were added to a playlist since last API request

Would like to make the "0" cost request of just fetching the videoIds before matching getting additional details about the Video in the playlist

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id&playlistId=PLlTLHnxSVuIyeEZPBIQF_krewJkY2JSwi&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The response is like below 
"items": [
  {

"kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/2wturocJM7aMkvG4Zrmv45tbyWY\"",
   "id": "UExsVExIbnhTVnVJeWVFWlBCSVFGX2tyZXdKa1kySlN3aS4xMjU2MjFGMDJBNEUzQzcw"
  },

The playlistItem id cannot be used in the video list to get additional info about the video and instead part:"snippet" which has a cost associated with it has to be added to the playlistItems request. Is this a bug or intentional ? Also is there a way to map the playlistItem-id to videoId/ResourceId ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, all calls have a cost. No matter what it is. Just how much depends on your request.

Yes, this is by design. They want to limit as much as possible the amount of calls to the system. This will make for better stream lining of call requests, as well as reducing strain on the site.